# Mobx how to compute values in state

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I'm new to Mobx and I can't work out how to compute a value in my store.

I'm following the [docs description of using the 'computed' modifier](https://doc.ebichu.cc/mobx/refguide/computed-decorator.html).

Here's my (cut down) appState:

```
export default class AppState {
    constructor() {
        /* MOBX STATE */
        extendObservable(this, {
            // Links
            'links': [],

            'updateLinks': action((newlinks) => {
                this.links = newlinks;
            }),

            'linksWithComments': computed(() => this.links),
        });
    }
}
```

'links' works fine in my React components, but when I add 'linksWithComments' I see this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [MobX] 'keys()' can only be used on observable objects, arrays, sets and maps
```

What am I doing wrong? 'links' is an array, and as far as I can tell it's observable, so what does the error mean? I've googled for the error message but haven't found anything that explains what's going on.

I've tried this form also:

```
get linksWithComments () { return 2*3; },
```

In this case 'linksWithComments' is undefined.

Versions:

```
"mobx": "^6.1.8",
"mobx-react": "^7.1.0",
"mobx-react-lite": "^3.2.0",
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferred way to use MobX@6 with classes is to use `makeAutoObservable` or `makeObservable`:

```js
class AppState {
  links = [];

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  updateLinks = (newLinks) => {
    this.links = newLinks;
  };

  get linksWithComments() {
    return this.links.filter((link) => link > 0.5);
  }
}
```

Have you tried it?

I've made [Codesanbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions67044061-70bim?file=/src/App.js) for you to explore!

[More info in the official docs](https://mobx.js.org/observable-state.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example. This construction does seem to work with my (heavily refactored!) code. I am still curious why my original code didn't work?

Comment: My guess is that `extendObservable` is not supposed to work with computed value or something like that. Anyway, it is better to use idiomatic ways from the docs